# Get list of file selected in FileUpload before upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, file-upload

Understand that `FileUpload.HasFiles, PostedFiles, FileName` will return the value correspondingly for the files selected. However, all these function calls can only be called when postback(E.g.`Button Click Event`which will cause `FileUpload` started to upload files selected).

The challenges:

1. I need the listing of files selected **before upload (PostBack)** and populate to `GridView`.
2. Users are allowed to add/delete files selected (`in FileUpload, listed in GridView`) in run-time.
3. File names get from `FileName` return full path in Internet Explorer while Chrome and Firefox return file name only (I need file name rather than full path for my case).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

you can only do it on the client side

```
var files=$('#ElementID').files;
 for (i=0;i<files.length;i++){
     $("#gridview2").append("<tr><td>" +files[i].fileName + 
                           "</td><td>" + files[i].fileSize + "</td></tr>");
  }
```